# Crear datos de un formulario al guardar los de otro formulario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito que al enviar los datos de un formulario, automaticamente envien los datos de otro formulario creando un registro en otra tabla en la base de datos, vale acotar que ambos registros no tienen una relacion directa.

estos serian los dos formularios

```
<%= form_for(@relcliruta, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %> <!--ajax remote: true-->


                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.hidden_field :IdRuta, value: params[:id]  %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.hidden_field :IdCliente, value: cliente.id%>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.hidden_field :IdEmpresa, value: current_usuario.empresa_id %>

                  </div>

                </div>

                <%= submit_tag "Añadir", class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs"%>
        <%end%>

        <%= form_for(@reldayc, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %> <!--ajax remote: true-->
          <%= f.hidden_field :RutaId, value: params[:id]  %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :CodCli, value: cliente.id%>
          <%= f.hidden_field :IdEmpresa, value: current_usuario.empresa_id %>

        <%end%>
```

Necesito que al crear uno, se cree el otro.

Comment: En las dos formas hay solo `hidden_field`. Las dos formas son iguales, salvo las variables de instancia por lo que los dos objetos tendrán la misma información. Tal vez te convenga más tener un solo objeto, o bien si necesitas los dos, entonces crear un método en tu controller que se encargue de crear los dos objetos sin necesidad de las formas. Y eso si, un botón para realizar la acción. El botón lo podrías crear con [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to). Espero esto te sea útil.

Comment: Como dice Horacio, lo mejor es que crees ambos elementos a nivel de controlador. Si tu forma se escapa de la típica relación 1 forma = 1 objeto, podrías probar a usar el patrón [form object](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects) para validar y guardar un objeto virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sería usando Javascript. Pero la pregunta tiene el tag *rails*, así que te cuento como hacerlo en Rails. (Ya lo adelantaron Horacio y Alter Lagos en los comentarios).

El Form:

NOTA: En tu ejemplo estás mezclando dos helpers de Rails. Usas el *form_for* pero en el botón usas *submit_tag* en vez de *f.submit*.

```
<%= form_tag route_creators_path, method: :post do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :IdRuta, params[:id]  %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :IdCliente, cliente.id%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :IdEmpresa, current_usuario.empresa_id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Añadir", class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs"%>
<%end%>
```

Controlador y ruta:

En el ejemplo estoy usando la acción *create* de un *RouteCreatorsController*. Podrías poner la acción donde te parezca.

```
#routes.rb
resources :route_creators, only: :create


# route_creators_controller.rb
class RouteCreatorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @route_id = params[:IdRute]
    @cliente_id = params[:IdCliente]
    @empresa_id = params[:IdEmpresa]
    #Me invento el nombre de los Objetos porque solo tengo el nombre de variable
    #Crea primer objeto
    RelCliRuta.create(
      IdRuta: @route_id,
      IdCliente: @cliente_id,
      IdEmpresa: @empresa_id
    )
    # Crea segundo objeto
    RelDayc.create(
      RutaId: @route_id,
      CodCli: @cliente_id,
      IdEmpresa: @empresa_id
    )
    redirect_to donde_quieras_ir_path
  end
end
```

Con esto logras tu objetivo. En cualquier caso siempre que empieces a usar form_tag o nested_attributes, te recomiendo que uses un *form_object* Abajo un ejemplo simplificado:

```
#routes.rb
resources :route_creators, only: :create


# route_creators_controller.rb
class RouteCreatorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    route_creator = RouteCreator.new(params[:route_id],
      params[:client_id],
      params[:company_id])
    route_creator.create_multiple

    redirect_to donde_quieras_ir_path
  end

end

class RouteCreator
  def initialize(route_id, client_id, company_id)
    @route_id = route_id
    @client_id = client_id
    @company_id = company_id
  end

  def create_multipe
    RelCliRuta.create(
      IdRuta: @route_id,
      IdCliente: @client_id,
      IdEmpresa: @company_id
    )
    RelDayc.create(
      RutaId: @route_id,
      CodCli: @client_id,
      IdEmpresa: @company_id
    )
  end
end
```